# Accessing and updating token stored in client side browser in getServerSideProps() in next js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js, seo

We're building an e-commerce project and we implemented jwt token logic. We use next js, react js and node js. I (in front-end) store token and refresh token in localStorage. There is a executeRequest function and all my fetch requests are made with it. If token expires it refreshes token and refetches all the requests. It was working fine till I needed to make the project SEO friendly. Now i need to fetch requests in server side and use returned data in meta tags in several pages like products and product page. The main problem is accessing and updating the token in client browser in server side fetching

Here is what I tried:

```
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Product from "../../components/product/Product";
import { withAuth } from "../../components/withAuth";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import Head from "next/head";
import {
  BACKEND_URL,
  fetchProductData,
  fixedPriceCalculator,
  getData,
} from "../../functions";
import useTranslation from "next-translate/useTranslation";
import { setProductData } from "../../store/productSlice";

function ProductPage({ uuid, data }) {
  const router = useRouter();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { title, description, image, productData } = useSelector(
    (state) => state.product
  );
  const { t } = useTranslation("common");
  const { locale } = router;
  const [breadcrumb, setBreadcrumb] = useState([
    { link: t("products"), active: false },
  ]);

  const afterDataFetched = (data) => {
    let tempBreadcrumbs = [...breadcrumb];
    if (tempBreadcrumbs?.length > 1) {
      tempBreadcrumbs.pop();
    }
    // dispatch(setTitle(data?.name));
    tempBreadcrumbs.push({ link: data?.name, active: true });
    setBreadcrumb(tempBreadcrumbs);
    let tempImages = data?.images?.length ? data?.images : [];
    if (data?.video) {
      tempImages.push({ type: "video", video: data?.video });
    }
    data = {
      ...data,
      discountPrice: fixedPriceCalculator(
        Number(data?.price) -
          (Number(data?.price) * Number(data?.discount)) / 100,
        data?.currency
      ),
      images: tempImages,
    };
    dispatch(
      setProductData({
        ...productData,
        [uuid]: { data: data, loading: false, error: false },
      })
    );
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    afterDataFetched(data);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    getData(
      {
        url: `${BACKEND_URL}/v1/items/${uuid}`,
        params: { language: locale, program: "web" },
      },
      (data) => {
        if (data !== "err") {
          afterDataFetched(data);
        } else {
          dispatch(
            setProductData({
              ...productData,
              [uuid]: { data: "", loading: false, error: true },
            })
          );
        }
      }
    );
  }, [locale]);

  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <title key="title">{title} | Timar</title>
        <meta name="description" key="description" content={description} />
        {title && (
          <meta
            property="og:title"
            content={`${title} | Timar`}
            key="og:title"
          />
        )}

        {image && (
          <meta
            property="og:image"
            content={`${BACKEND_URL}/images/items/${image}`}
          />
        )}
        <meta property="og:image:type" content="image/png" />
        <meta property="og:image:width" content="1200" />
        <meta property="og:image:height" content="630" />
      </Head>
      <Product uuid={router.query.uuid} breadcrumb={breadcrumb} />
    </>
  );
}

export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  const { locale, params } = context;
  // Fetch the product UUID from the params
  const { uuid } = params;

  // Fetch the product data using your API fetch function
  const data = await fetchProductData(uuid, locale);

  // Pass the UUID as a prop to the component
  return {
    props: {
      uuid,
      data,
    },
  };
}

export default withAuth(ProductPage);

const refreshTokenFunction = async (refreshToken) => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.post(
      `${BACKEND_URL}/v1/auth/refresh`,
      {
        refreshToken,
        program: "web",
      },
      {
        headers: {
          Authorization: token ? `Bearer ${token}` : "",
        },
      }
    );
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      localStorage.setItem("token", response.data.token);
      localStorage.setItem("refreshToken", response.data.refreshToken);

      let decodedTokenRefreshed = jwt_decode(response.data.token);
      store.dispatch(setToken(decodedTokenRefreshed));
      resolve(response.data.token);
    });
  } catch (error) {
    if (error.response && error?.response?.status === 409) {
      handleLogout();
      store.dispatch(setIsTokenConflictModalOpen(true));
      Router.push("/");
      return null;
    } else if (error?.response && error?.response?.status === 403) {
      store.dispatch(setIsBlocked(true));
      Router.push("/blocked");
      return "blocked";
    } else {
      throw error;
    }
  }
};

let refreshInProgress = false;
let requestQueue = [];
let requestCounter = 0;

// Function to execute a request with a callback
const executeRequest = async (request, callback, paramToken = "") => {
  token = paramToken || localStorage.getItem("token");
  const { url, method, body = {}, params = null } = request;
  let refreshTokenBlocked = false;
  try {
    const response = await axios({
      url,
      method,
      data: body,
      params,
      headers: {
        Authorization: token ? `Bearer ${token}` : "",
      },
    });
    callback(response.data, 200);
  } catch (error) {
    if (error.response && error?.response?.status === 401) {
      if (token) {
        if (!refreshInProgress) {
          refreshInProgress = true;
          try {
            refreshToken = localStorage.getItem("refreshToken");
            const refreshResponse = await refreshTokenFunction(refreshToken);
            if (refreshResponse) {
              refreshInProgress = false;
              if (refreshResponse !== "blocked") {
                token = refreshResponse;
                if (token) {
                  // requestQueue.forEach((queuedRequest) =>
                  //   executeRequest(
                  //     queuedRequest.request,
                  //     queuedRequest.callback,
                  //     refreshResponse,
                  //     true
                  //   )
                  // );
                  await Promise.all(
                    requestQueue.map(async (queuedRequest) => {
                      await executeRequest(
                        queuedRequest.request,
                        queuedRequest.callback,
                        refreshResponse,
                        true
                      );
                    })
                  );
                }
              } else {
                refreshTokenBlocked = true;
              }
              requestQueue = [];
              requestCounter = 0;
            }
          } catch (error) {
            callback(null, error?.response?.status);
          }
        }
      }
      // If refresh is already in progress or there's no token, add request to queue
      requestQueue.push({ request: { ...request }, callback });
      requestCounter++;
    } else if (error.response && error?.response?.status === 403) {
      store.dispatch(setIsBlocked(true));
      Router.push("/blocked");
      return "";
    } else {
      console.log(error);
      callback("err", error?.response?.status, error?.response?.data);
    }
  } finally {
    if (!refreshTokenBlocked) {
      requestCounter--;
      if (requestCounter === 0 && requestQueue.length > 0) {
        const queuedRequest = requestQueue.shift();
        executeRequest(queuedRequest.request, queuedRequest.callback);
      }
    }
  }
};

// Function to make a GET request with a callback
export const getData = (fetchData, callback) => {
  const { url, params = null } = fetchData;
  executeRequest({ url, method: "GET", params }, callback);
};

export const fetchProductData = (uuid, locale) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    getData(
      {
        url: `${BACKEND_URL}/v1/items/${uuid}`,
        params: { language: locale, program: "web" },
      },
      (responseData, status) => {
        if (status === 200) {
          resolve(responseData);
        } else {
          reject(new Error(`Failed to fetch product data. Status: ${status}`));
        }
      }
    );
  });
};
```

Comment: LocalStorage inst available in serverside. Maybe you could change it to use cookies instead. Link to the docs https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/upgrading/app-router-migration#accessing-request-object.

Comment: Thank you for your response! If token expires or token doesn't exist i need to get token first and set it to cookie. Will I( in front-end) be able to set token to cookie in server side as well?